# How can I get the IP address from computer name?

Tags: sockets, ip, fileshare

How can I get the IP address from a string such as '\\myserver'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
public static System.Net.IPAddress GetRemoteIpV4Address(string hostNameOrIpAddress)
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostNameOrIpAddress))
  {
    return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrIpAddress).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) ??
      new System.Net.IPAddress(new byte[] { 147, 0, 0, 1 });
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()`.